# prove this is a closed nowhere dense subset in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A UC qualiyfing exam problem goes like this:

Let $f$ be a positive continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{|t|\rightarrow\infty} f(t)=0$. Show that the set $\{hf|\,h\in L^1(\mathbb{R}),||h||_1\leq K\}$ is a closed nowhere dense set in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for any $K>0$.

The second part: let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of positive continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $n$ we have $\lim_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}f_n(t)=0$. Show that there exists $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g/f_n\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for any $n$.

The second part is clear from the first part and the Baire category theorem. The first part got me stuck for a day now. If we assume closedness, we can see "nowhere denseness" as follows: let $h$ be a function with $||h||_1\leq K$; first we can find a sequence of disjoint subsets $E_n$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f|<\frac{1}{n}$ on $E_n$ and $\mu(E_n)=1$ for each $n$. Let $g$ be the function that is $\frac{1}{n}$ on $E_n$ and zero elsewhere, then $gf\in L^1$ but $g\notin L^1$. Therefore for any $\epsilon>0$, we see that $hf+\epsilon gf\notin$ the set defined in the problem. This shows that the interior of the set defined in the problem is empty.

But for closedness,I couldn't prove directly using measure theory, or the fact that convergence in $L^1$ implies a subsequence converges pointwise. I also tried to use Fourier transform to transform to change multiplication into convolution. But $f$ doesn't have to have a Fourier transform. Can someone give me some hints as to what should I try? Thank you!!

Comment: Please write an *informative* title the describes the *content* of the problem, not merely its origin.  Also... what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $h_nf\to g$ in $L^1,$ where each $\|h_n\|_1\le K.$ Then $|h_n|f\to |g|$ in $L^1.$ Thus $|h_n|f\to (|g|/f)f$ in $L^1.$ It follows that $|h_{n_k}|f \to (|g|/f)f$ a.e. for some subsequence, which implies $|h_{n_k}| \to (|g|/f)$ a.e. By Fatou's lemma,

$$\int (|g|/f) = \int \liminf |h_{n_k}| \le \liminf \int  |h_{n_k}| \le K.$$

This shows $g=(g/f)f$ with $\|g/f\|_1\le K,$ and thus the set in question is closed.

Comment: Huh, I can't believe that I totally forgot about Fatou's lemma.